# Is there any way to open URL in chrome from android splash browser?

Tags: javascript, android, splash-screen

I am trying to open a URL from android's splash browser (browser that opens when your connect to WiFi and it pops up to ask for authentication), basically it is a WebView and I want to open a URL in phone's google chrome browser.

I have already tried intents like this:

```
<a href="intent://www.example.com#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;">Open Link</a>
```

and it is working perfectly if I try to open it from Firefox, but same is not working with Splash screen as mentioned.

Comment: try to set brodcast receiver that watch wifi network. and open your app